# Revert to design-time TImage picture

Tags: delphi, timage

How to revert to default design-time assigned picture of TImage component in Delphi XE+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control does not keep track of any previous images. So, you will need to do one of the following:

1. Find a way to get hold of the image from the .dfm file when you need to revert.
2. Make a note of the original image when the form is created, and restore that when you need to revert.

Option 1 is very messy, I do not recommend it. So, I suggest you go for option 2.

Comment: A highly inefficient but easy implementation of 1 is to create a dummy form of the same class and assign the picture before freeing the dummy form.